# Demangling and <sstream> results in "ambiguous reference to __gnu_gxx namespace"

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, template-meta-programming, demangler

When I need to print type info at runtime, I always apply demangling to `std::type_info::name()` result. This is the implementation for GCC, which uses [`abi::__cxa_demangle()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html):

```
#include <cxxabi.h>

GCC demangling implementation
std::string demangle(  const std::string& name )
{ 
    int status;

    return std::string( abi::__cxa_demangle( name.c_str() , 0 , 0 , &status ) );

    return name;
}
```

Today I was writting a `to_string` template which allows me to print the content of a typelist. So to avoid `std::string`concatenations, I used a string stream, `std::ostringstream`:

```
template<typename T>
struct to_string_t
{
    operator std::string()
    {
        return demangle( typeid( T ).name() );
    }
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct to_string_t<mpl::list<Ts...>>
{
    operator std::string()
    {
        std::ostringstream os;

        os << '[' << _to_string<mpl::list<Ts...>>() << ']';

        return os.str();
    }
};
```

`_to_string` is a class template which implements `operator<<`to print recursively the content of the typelist to the stream. *(I don't include it to not bloat the post with non-related metaprogramming code)*.

This works perfectly **without demangling**. When I include `<cxxabi>` to implement the demangling, the compiler shows an `ambiguous reference to __gnu_gxx namespace` error in `sstream.h`.

**What could be the reason?**

Comment: version of gcc? gcc 4.8 compile this snippet fine.

Comment: Without a compilable example, I had to guess to put a file together, but having done so it compiled without error with `g++` 4.8.1. Please provide a complete example (I just want to be able to do an exact copy-paste-compile), and the exact command you are using to compile. Also, which gcc version may matter. And for kicks, which boost version.

Comment: @BoBTFish Sorry. Im using g++ 4.8.1. Im going to edit the question to include the complete code.